# Android java unable to download file

Tags: java, android, download

am trying to download file from server , but no success my code seems to be ok

```
URL url = null;
URLConnection con = null;
  int i;
   try {
url = new URL(downlink);    // url : http://10.0.2.2:800/myproject/down/file9.txt
con = url.openConnection();
String dest_path = c.getFilesDir().getPath() + "/textfile.txt"; //Download Location set to : /data/data/com.myproject.androidt/files/textfile.txt
File file = new File(dest_path);
     BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
     FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput("textfile.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
     BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
     while ((i = bis.read()) != -1) {
     bos.write(i);
         }
     bos.flush();
     bis.close();
     return true;
     } catch (MalformedInputException malformedInputException) {
     Log.d("dark","Failure : MalformedInputException occured in downloading");
          // error in download
     return false;
     } catch (IOException ioException) {
     Log.d("dark","Failure : IO Error occured in downloading");
     return false;
       // error in download
     }
```

so please help i get IO exception  , do not know what's wrong with code :(

Comment: which line is throwing the exception

Comment: @todd   this line thrown exception :                             BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file.getName()));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have to call the `openFileOutput` method to get the `FileOutputStream`

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("textfile.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

and you only need the file name not the path.

Comment: Thanks you save my day :) now it works ..... i do not need full path   , the problem was i was passing full path

Comment: do you know how to delete app folder in android debug monitor , i cant delete folders that i created in my app data folder